# Resolving a conflict on tortoise

Tags: tortoisesvn, conflict

I recently asked a question about committing a new file but now I am having trouble resolving a conflict.

Says

SOURCE LEFT 
SOURCE RIGHT

how do you want to resolve...

gives me choices to merge changes into a new file or mark as resolved- neither really works. when i mark as resolved i get a big red x and when i merge its still not letting me overwrite as the file over the conflicted file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have resolved the conflicts and saved then you should be able to use the command "TortoiseSVN -> Resolved" to mark the file as resolved. This should then allow you to commit your changes to the repository.

More information about TortoiseSVN merges can be found [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html)

Comment: Note that the "Resolved" command does not actually perform the merge or resolve conflicts. Rather it tells TortoiseSVN that you have finished resolving conflicts and are ready to commit.